# grep struggle - whole path match only

Tags: bash, path, grep

I have separated (by ":" symbol) the path from the file name in order to grep more easily. I've read a lot of questions, but none of suggested solutions worked in this case.

**My list:**

```
  1 /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_2.sh 
  2 /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_1.sh 
  3 /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_3.sh 
  4 /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_7.sh 
  5 /c/Users/Michael/desktop/here : myfile.sh 
  6 /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_7.sh 
  7 /c/Users/Michael/desktop/here : myfile.sh 
  8 /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_7.sh 
  9 /c/Users/Michael/desktop/here : myfile.sh 
 10 /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_7.sh 
 11 /c/Users/Michael/desktop/here @ myfile.sh
```

**Output I need:**

```
  /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_2.sh 
  /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_1.sh 
  /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_3.sh 
  /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_7.sh
  /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_7.sh 
  /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_7.sh 
  /c/Users/Michael : tutorial_7.sh
```

**when I go like:**

```
$ grep /c/Users/Michael ~/desktop/list
```

**output is:**

```
The whole list (prints all records)
```

**Also tried:**

```
grep -E '(^|\s)/c/Users/Michael($|/s)' ~/desktop/list
```

**output is:**

```
nothing
```

**Also tried:**

```
grep "\<"/c/Users/Michael"\>" ~/desktop/list
```

**output is:**

```
nothing
```

**Also tried:**

```
$ grep -w /c/Users/Michael ~/desktop/list
```

**output is:**

```
The whole list (prints all records)
```

Comment: What are you looking for?  Files in directory `/c/Users/Michael` or files matching `tutorial_[0-9]+.sh` or something else?  Since your examples are looking for `/c/Users/Michael`, it suggests the former; so search for the space: `grep -e '^/c/Users/Michael ' ~/desktop/list`.  Use single quotes around regexes in shell scripts unless you're masochistic.

Comment: Your last example uses `/c/Users/Martin` and lists everything?  That seems improbable; you presumably meant `/c/Users/Michael` again.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the space to the pattern you're grepping for:

```
grep "/c/Users/Michael " ~/desktop/list
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a space (`\`) after `Michael` and use `-o`:

```
$ grep -o /c/Users/Michael\ .* file
/c/Users/Michael : tutorial_2.sh 
/c/Users/Michael : tutorial_1.sh 
/c/Users/Michael : tutorial_3.sh 
/c/Users/Michael : tutorial_7.sh 
/c/Users/Michael : tutorial_7.sh 
/c/Users/Michael : tutorial_7.sh 
/c/Users/Michael : tutorial_7.sh
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question. What if I would like to save  this expression into the variable? ... Path='$/c/Users/Michael\' ... It only works when the " \ " is not the last character.

Comment: When I tried Path='$/c/Users/Michael\' and used this variable in grep, output was: "grep: Trailing backslash" ....... double quotes in the previous comment, ruined while editing

Comment: `foo="/c/Users/Michael .*"` and `grep -o "$foo" file`

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '$2 == "/c/Users/Michael" { print $2" "$3" " $4 }' file
```